# Bootstrap thumbnail same height and align div to bottom in LESS

Tags: css, less

I am using bootstrap thumbnails(http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#thumbnails) and I want to have them all be the height of the tallest in that particular "ul" (if i have 2 thumbnails "ul" the first set of thumbnail "li"s should be X height and the second set Y height).

In addition, I have a div inside the thumbnail that I want at the bottom of the each thumbnail. For example in the following picture everything from the "Berkeley, CA" and under is at the bottom of each thumbnail regardless of the height and amount of content above. How do I do this? Thanks!

[image]

I have tried the following to get the heights to be the same, but it doesn't do anything for some reason :(

```
.thumbnails {    
    &.uniform > li {
         height: 100%;
    }
}

%ul{ :class => 'thumbnails uniform' }
  - category.ideas.each do |idea|
    %li{ :class => "span3" }
      %a{ :href => idea_path(idea.id), :class => 'thumbnail', :id => "idea_#{idea.id}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was put the top part of my thumbnail into a div and have those all equal the the height of the longest of those divs. This worked for me because the bottom part was all the same height.